# Which constructor is called here, move or copy?

Tags: c++, copy-constructor, move-constructor

In the code below, which constructor will be called, the move constructor or copy constructor?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void called(std::string value)
{
    cout << "Value is " << value << endl;
}

int main()
{
    called("I am good");
}
```

Comment: unclear. To move you need a string first that can be moved from. Do you expect that first a string is constructed from the string literal and then it is moved or copied?

Comment: In C++17 neither move nor copy is called, only the constructor to create string from `const char*`. Before C++17, it may call move constructor, but it may be also optimized away.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number, Yes, I expect a temporary to be created.

Answer (score 2):

A `std::string` is constructed from your `const char[]`, therefore we then have a temporary. This will then be moved from or the constructor call will be elided altogether before C++17. As of C++17, elision is guaranteed and no move or copy constructor will be called. See: [description on cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision)